# Se puede asociar dos variables a una mismo índice en un array?

Tags: php, array

tengo la siguiente duda de si puedo hacer que en un array asociativo se pueda usar la misma asociación en dos variables diferentes o más dentro del mismo arreglo, la forma en la que estoy guardando las variables en el array es así:

```
case 0:{ 
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['codigo'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Caja_Venta'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Porductos']; 
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Fecha'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Total'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['TresPorDomingo'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['CincoPorDomingo'];                     
}
break;
case 1:{
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['codigo'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Caja_Venta'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Porductos']; 
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Fecha'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['Total'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['TresPorLunes'];
$VentasComisionables[] = $row['CincoPorLunes'];                    
}
```

si bien para acceder a ellas es mediante el número no me parece muy práctico ya que son diferentes variables que van organizadas por un `switch` y el  `case` se extiende hasta 6 uno por cada día de la semana , tenía algo en mente de hacer lo siguiente pero por obvias razones funciona solo que agrega el ultimo valor a la asociación:

```
case 0:{ 
$VentasComisionables['Codigo'] = $row['codigo'];
$VentasComisionables['Caja'] = $row['Caja_Venta'];
$VentasComisionables['Producto'] = $row['Porductos']; 
$VentasComisionables['Fecha'] = $row['Fecha'];
$VentasComisionables['Total'] = $row['Total'];
$VentasComisionables['3%'] = $row['TresPorDomingo'];
$VentasComisionables['5%'] = $row['CincoPorDomingo'];                     
}
break;
case 1:{
$VentasComisionables['Codigo'] = $row['codigo'];
$VentasComisionables['Caja'] = $row['Caja_Venta'];
$VentasComisionables['Producto'] = $row['Porductos']; 
$VentasComisionables['Fecha'] = $row['Fecha'];
$VentasComisionables['Total'] = $row['Total'];
$VentasComisionables['3%'] = $row['TresPorLunes'];
$VentasComisionables['5%'] = $row['CincoPorLunes'];                    
}
```

Comment: No entendí, qué es lo que no te funciona???. Por otro lado podrías crear una clase para guardar los elementos. También podrías sacar los primeros 5 valores fuera del switch, así te queda más corto el código

Comment: el primer bloque de código funciona bien , solo tenía esa duda de si podría agregar el mismo índice dos variables como en el segundo bloque de código ya que si lo hago así solo se agrega las ultimas variables

Comment: Los arreglos pueden ser multi-dimensión, ej: `$ventas[0]['Codigo']` y `$ventas[1]['Codigo']` ó `$ventas['Caja'][0]` y `$ventas['Caja'][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Obviamente, lo que preguntas es imposible. En un array, un índice identifica un único elemento del array. No puedes tener dos elementos bajo un mismo índice.

Cuando usas:

```
$array[] = 'loQueSea';
```

Estás añadiendo un elemento nuevo al array, porque no estás indicando índice. Esto va muy bien para arrays numéricos (donde los índices son enteros).

Pero cuando usas:

```
$array['miIndice'] = 'loQueSea';
```

Estás asignando valor a un elemento concreto del array, el identificado por el índice `'miIndice'`. Si no existe ese elemento (ese índice) en el array, lo crea, pero si ya existe, **sobrescribe su valor**.

De forma que, en tu ejemplo, cuando dices que "solo se agrega las ultimas variables", en realidad lo que estará pasando es que la primera vez se crean los elementos, pero luego se van sobrescribiendo sus valores, de forma que al final quedan los valores del último `$row` que se procesó.